# Image segmentation based on mouse click

Tags: image, image-processing

Using python framework we are able to create image segments as shown in attachment. Now, based on the mouse click in the image segment we need to highlight the segment with specific color.

Based on the mouse click I am able to get x/y coordinates of the specific location. Please suggest me how can I check on which image segment the coordinates belongs to?

The following is the code snippet:

```
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb, slic,quickshift
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.segmentation import find_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import measure
from skimage import restoration
from skimage import img_as_float

import numpy as np

coords = []

def find_nearest(array,value):

    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()

    return array[idx]

def onclick(event):

    global ix, iy

    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata

    print ('ix ',ix)

    print ("iy ",iy)

    color = np.float64([1,0,1]) # red color

    image[segments == 14] = color

    mark_boundaries(image, segments)

    ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(image, segments))

    coords.append((ix, iy))

    return

image=img_as_float(io.imread("amazon.jpg"))

segments = quickshift(image, ratio=1.0, kernel_size=20, max_dist=10,
           return_tree=False, sigma=0, convert2lab=True, random_seed=42)

fig = plt.figure("Superpixels -- %d segments" % (500))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

color = np.float64([1,0,0]) 

image[segments == 14] = color  # desired segment to be colored

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(image, segments))

plt.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image: image attached]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.quickshift), `quickshift` returns an integer mask indicating segment labels. If you know what pixel the user clicked on, you can check the value of that pixel in your variable `segments` to get the segment number.

In you click handler, you can use
`clicked_segment = segments[event.xdata, event.ydata]`

Comment: The following is the code added in click method:                           **clicked_segment = segments[event.xdata, event.ydata] <br/>
image[clicked_segment ] = color         mark_boundaries(image, segments) 
fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.update() 
fig.canvas.flush_events()**  But still the color is not updated in the required segment. Pls suggest

Comment: my matplotlib version: 1.5.3  and Python version 3.5.2

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned this: `clicked_segment` is a scalar value that corresponds to the labeled region in the `segments` matrix. You still need to use logical array indexing when you set the color. `image[segments==clicked_segment]=color`

Comment: i tried with the updated code but still the issue is persisting. can u pls send the complete code ?  The **code image[segments == 10] = color** is working perfectly outside the click method

Comment: I don't have complete code, and I don't know how to fix your click method. However, if you want to check which segment the coordinates belong to (as you said in your question), you can get that with `clicked_segment = segments[x, y]`. You may want to check to make sure that your mouse coordinates actually align with the image coordinates.

Comment: Also, "the color is not updated in the required segment" could mean a variety of things. Is it not updating at all? Is it updating the wrong segment? Can you provide some more details?

Comment: Thanks matthew.. i got the answer. on every click i saved every segment  into separate image which was saving successfuly but In the existing image it was not updating maybe i need to check how to get the updated image on the fly.